# assets:precompile fails with Invalid argument on Rails 3.2.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake, asset-pipeline

Seeing a very odd issue when i am trying to precompile assets.

Gemfile:

```
# Asset pipeline
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier',     '1.3.0'
end
```

production.rb

```
  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css )

  # Choose which compressors to use
  # config.assets.js_compressor  = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :scss
```

I run,

```
rm -rf tmp
rm -rf public/assets
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:clean
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake --trace assets:precompile
```

And get:

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 /usr/local/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
rake aborted!
Invalid argument - /net/s/code/user/app/tmp/cache/assets/E5E/3A0/sprockets%2Fe69b4abed0b5dae08d5bef64de8361ec
```

The file in question is created on disk.

Any ideas what on earth this means?

Thanks

Comment: I think you have some syntax error in some assets file. Recheck it.

Comment: How can i tell which file to check?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to know which file has a syntax error. You have to check all files at once. Use some external tools like www.jshint.com to check it.

Comment: Try doing `rake tmp:cache:clear` , then precompile your assets